# Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I convert the old asp.net VB code to new.

I got this errors like the following:

```
Dim strArray(,) As String (0 To .,0 To .) = New String(11 - 1, (num + 1) - 1) {}

//Error : Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers


strArray = DirectCast(Utils.CopyArray(DirectCast(strArray, Array), New String((num9 + 1) - 1, (num + 1) - 1) {}), String(0 To .,0 To .)(,))

//Error strArray is not declared.
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the array like this...

```
Dim num As Integer = 0 'I just added this as a variable
Dim strArray(,) As String = New String(11 - 1, (num + 1) - 1) {}
```